# Excel - How do I use a cell value in one sheet to go to another value on a separate sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I have a spot where the person will enter in their date they want to find and I want them to be able to push 'GO', this part is easy. I want it to look in another data sheet and go to and select the cell that corresponds with the value they put in the first sheet.

For reference in my code below 'HomeSheet' is the user page where they enter the data. 'DataSheet' is the page I want them to be directed to when they push the button.

Current code is giving me an error on the 3rd to last row where it's trying to select the cell it found that corresponded with the input date on the HomeSheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim valueToFind

    valueToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Homesheet").Range("I8")
    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")
    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:ZZ1")

    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
        Sheets("DataSheet").Range(xlCell).Select
        End If
    Next xlCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Just do `xlCell.Select`. You've already declared `xlCell` as a `Range`, so no need to wrap it in `Range()`.

Comment: I've tried this as well, unfortunately it gives a different error 'Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this propert or method.

Comment: what is your active sheet when you're running this code?

Comment: The code is attached to a command button on HomeSheet, I want it to search on DataSheet and select a cell on DataSheet

Comment: then add a 'xlSheet.Activate' before that select line.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!